# How to increase the maximum number of lights in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I'm experimenting with Three.js and I'm trying to increase the number of lights that I can use in a scene. Theoretically this number should be limited only by the GPU, resulting in a drop in the frame rate, but apparently if I try to put more than 128 lights the entire material became white.

I'm using a MeshPhongMaterial and I'm adding simple PointLights

```
for(var i=0; i < maxLights; i++) {
    var alpha = 2 * Math.PI / maxLights * i;

    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0x376cf5, 1, 0.3 );

    pointLight.position.x = Math.cos(alpha) * lightRadius;
    pointLight.position.z = Math.sin(alpha) * lightRadius;
    pointLights.push(pointLight);

    scene.add( pointLight );
}
```

I think that the limitation is the number of bits used for addressing lights.

If my hypothesis is correct, is there some reason for this limitation? Given enough implementation time on my end, what are the challenges that I'll face if I'll try to fix this limitation?

Thank you.

Comment: If i have to guess I say u (three.js) reached the maximum number of uniforms the GPU can use at same time.

Comment: If you want to support that many lights, you need to [bring back](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7095) `THREE.WebGLDeferredRenderer`. http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_lights_deferred_pointlights.html